# Mysql query not working with IST timezone

Tags: php, mysql

I have table "bookings" in mysql and i want to fetch those record whose "bookingtime"(data type is "Datetime") more than 40 minutes ( according to IST)
My query not working with IST,

Here is my table "booking"

```
id      name        bookingtime
1       ayhd        2020-01-09 15:23:33
2       dhdye       2020-01-09 14:53:38
3       juey        2020-01-09 11:13:53
```

I tried with following query but not showing any result,Where i am wrong ?

```
SELECT * FROM booking
WHERE bookingtime < (NOW() - INTERVAL 40 MINUTE)
```

Comment: your query is working fine for me.

Comment: where you are running query? on local or on server?

Comment: may be  you had set IST timezone in your code but mysql will take server timezone for  `NOW() - INTERVAL 40 MINUTE`. so, basically do not store `bookingtime` in IST or do not use mysql function in where clause

Comment: There's no need to guess. Start by doing some basic diagnostics. Please run something like `select distinct bookingtime, now(), NOW() - INTERVAL 40 MINUTE` and draw some conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

try this query , it will get records between now and 40 minutes ago

```
SELECT * FROM `booking` WHERE `bookingtime` >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 40 MINUTE) AND `bookingtime` < NOW()
```

Comment: in your database , bookingtime is stored in IST time ?